# integration testing I18n for subdomain in Angular/Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, internationalization, capybara

I am trying to test my translations using capybara on an angular/rails app.  I have a before action in the application controller that checks for a subdomain in the url and sets the locale accordingly.

In order to manually test in the browser I have to modify my /hosts/etc file to include the subdomain that I am trying to test.  The service currently works but I want to write an integration test around it.

I found this: http://www.chrisaitchison.com/2013/03/17/testing-subdomains-in-rails/  which seems like it would be a solid solution but it doesn't work for me.  Every time I try to run the test the I18n.locale is still set to the default locale rather than the locale based off of the subdomain.

Is there a way to write integration tests around this that don't involve me expecting the page to have content?  My test currently looks like:

```
context "no subdomain present", js: true do
    it "sets the locale to the default when no valid subdomain is present" do
      visit '/'
      expect(I18n.locale).to eq(I18n.default_locale)
    end
  end

  context "with a subdomain present", js: true do
    it "sets the locale based on the subdomain" do
      visit "hindi.127.0.0.1.xip.io:#{Capybara.server_port}/"
      sleep(2)
      expect(I18n.locale).to eq('hi')
    end
  end
```

The top test passes of course but the bottom one doesn't. Thanks in advance and let me know if I am forgetting anything and I will add it asap.

Comment: did you try `"http://hindi.127.0.0.1.xip.io:#{Capybara.server_port}/"`?

Comment: Yes I did and that resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a controller test if you don't want to test page content:

```
describe SomeController do
  it "sets the locale to the default when no valid subdomain is present" do
    get :index
    expect(I18n.locale).to eq(I18n.default_locale)
  end
  it "sets locale from subdomain" do
    get :index, subdomain: 'hindu'
    expect(I18n.locale).to eq('hi')
  end
end
```

Comment: I try to use controller specs whenever I have to do a database query or check some rails internal in my expectations. You want to keep your features all about testing from an end user perspective (If i do x, I should see x on the screen).

Comment: I can't do a controller test(As far as I know) because Angular takes care of all of the routing for the app.  So get :index => Failure/Error: get :index
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"application"}

Comment: Thats doesn't sound right - Angular may handle the routing client side but Rails needs routes to be able respond to any kind of request. Check the output of `$ rake routes`

Comment: rake routes =>     Prefix Verb URI Pattern                Controller#Action
guides GET  /guides(.:format)          guides#index
 guide GET  /guides/:id(.:format)      guides#show
       GET  /                          application#layout
       GET  /pages/*template(.:format) application#page
errors POST /errors(.:format)          application#error
  page GET  /*path(.:format)           application#layout
  root GET  /                          application#layout

Comment: Well, adapt the the test to one of the routes which actually exist.